# Dynamic where clause and operand SQL Server

Tags: sql, dynamic, where-clause, clause

Having read almost all topics related to dynamic where clauses, I still can't find a way through.

Here is my source table:

[Source Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA6tY.jpg)

And the result I want is:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h212.jpg)

In fact I want to return all values satisfying the Test value condition but don't know how to implement it dynamicly (I have a table with 700K lines).

Thanks a lot for your help.

EDIT:

Following your answers, I will detailed a bit more the approach.
Unfortunately, as I'm a new user, I'm not allowed to post pictures directly in the post.

I'm basicly performing segregation of duties controls over the SAP system.
Basicly, I want to test if some of the access of a customer are conflictual based on SAP extractions against a knowledge template stating potential conflicts.

Here is an simplified example of the SAP extract:

And here is a simplified example of the Potential conflict template:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Field</th><th>Value</th></tr><tr><td>ACTVT</td><td>AZ0220</td></tr><tr><td>KOART</td><td>K</td></tr><tr><td>BUKRS</td><td>*</td></tr><tr><td>EKGRP</td><td>03</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

This is a faxe example of the raw data of the customer:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>FIELD</th><th>RANGE_START</th><th>RANGE_END</th></tr><tr><td>ACTVT</td><td>AZ01*</td><td>AZ99*</td></tr><tr><td>KOART</td><td>A</td><td>L</td></tr><tr><td>BUKRS</td><td>011</td><td>099</td></tr><tr><td>EKGRP</td><td>2</td><td>10</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I thought a way of doing this is to use dynamic where clause.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Please update your question.  Post the images directly into the editor rather than linking.  And provide information on your source table with the 700K lines.  Then show us a way you have tried.

Comment: It looks like you are going to have make a dynamic statement for each row.  This suggests to me a bad design -- but it is really hard to tell without knowning more.